# Android SDK r 15 error: Cannot build project using Ant

Tags: android, ant, build

```
Buildfile: /Users/satya/project/bitzer_android_code/build.xml
     [echo] /Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86

BUILD FAILED
/Users/satya/project/bitzer_android_code/build.xml:64: taskdef class com.android.ant.AaptExecLoopTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/anttasks.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/common.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/sdklib.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/androidprefs.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/mkidentity.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/commons-compress-1.0.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/satya/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar]
```

Comment: does this help?:http://openremote.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12845735&focusedCommentId=12845790

Comment: or this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4605369/644450